# String to Long conversion in Talend

Tags: type-conversion, talend

I have an Excel input which I want to copy in SQL table.
I am taking an input as a string and need to convert it in long to copy in SQL table.

My workflow is Excel input -> tMap -> tMSSqlOutput.
I have used below expression for the conversion:
row4.accesstype  == null ? null : Long.parseLong(row4.accesstype)

But I am getting an error which says:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "accesstype_key1"

May I know where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"accesstype_key1" is obviously not going to convert to a Long, it's a string. Check your input data.